# How to get datetime on datetime-local via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have datetime-local html control on my form and I need to get date and time of it dynamically via jQuery.  How can I do it?

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="publishDate" />
```

I tried

```
$("#publishDate").val();
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: It only gets a value if you have selected a complete date & time.  Anything else it returns nothing.  Just give it an initial value when you create it.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gE5U2/1/)  Give initial value. **Remember to give both date and time -values!**

```
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Local Datetime field</h3>

<input type="datetime-local" id="publishDate" value="2014-11-16T15:25:33">

<p>Click the button to get the local date and time of the datetime field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("publishDate").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works nicely, but it doesn't emphasize the reason why my code didn't work (ie. I didn't fill the whole date and TIME)